# Get date from file instead of declaring it inside the js file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can I make it so I get the date from a file like a config file for example instead of putting it inside every js file.

```
var d = new Date("July 21, 1983 01:15:00");
```

Comment: Ajax call?  Include a secondary script file on your pages that has that specific value in it?  Various ways to do this.  You're asking a very broad question.

Comment: Well, could you give me one very simple way of doing it. Like "var d = new Date("filename.config");

Comment: If I give you one way, and a second user gives you another way, and another use gives you yet another way, and they all work, which one is the right answer?  As I said, your question is too broad.  You need to reduce the scope of your question and ask about a specific approach.  And explain any issues you are having doing it yourself.

Comment: It's just that I don't know how to do it and need a way to do it, if it works then great, if it doesn't work i'll find out why. Im building a web-browser based game where I use iframe to load the questions, the thing is the quiz needs to be based on time since if you answer incorrect you lose and should be redirected out and if you answer right you get redirected to a new question. The thing is since these are all new pages I have to have different javascripts for the to redirect to next page and not just redirect to the same page and if they are all based around the same time I need a file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the ways you could do this could be including a separate file on the same page like so:

```
<script src="date.js"></script>
```

date.js:

```
var d = new Date("July 21, 1983 01:15:00");
```

---

Another way you could do it is by using jQuery's `$.getScript()` like so:

date.js:

```
var d = new Date("July 21, 1983 01:15:00");
```

index.html:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<script>
    $.getScript("date.js", data => $("body").append($("<script>" + data + "</script");
</script>
```

---

Both of these methods will result in this code:

```
var d = new Date("July 21, 1983 01:15:00");
```

Being accessible on your page.

Hopefully this helps!